# Reliable way to access data in Polymer (inside dom-repeat / event handler)

Tags: events, polymer, shadow-dom

I need to capture data from an instance generated by `<template is="dom-repeat">` in Polymer (v1.2.4) and I am not sure what would be the safest way to do so considering the myriad of Shadow DOMs available (client browser might be polyfilled etc).

A simple example:

`<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[myItems]]" id="collection">
    <paper-card on-tap="handleTap">
        (...)`

### What is the most reliable way to access the model data from the event handler?

#### 1.

`handleTap: function(e) {
    var data = e.model.get('item.myData');
}`

#### 2.

`handleTap: function(e) {
    var data = this.$.collection
        .modelForElement(Polymer.dom(e).localTarget)
        .get('item.myData');
}`

My concern is that the simplest (#1) option might be working as expected in *my* environment but can get buggy in other browsers.

And even in option #2, I am not confident if it is really necessary to normalize the event target (as recommended in the [official Polymer guide on events](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html#retargeting)) prior to passing it to `modelForElement`.

Comment: Regarding #1 and browser behavior, how about setting up unit tests and running them in [Sauce Labs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/tools/tests.html#automated-testing-in-the-cloud)?

Answer (score 0):

Both should work; but, it seems you should fire a custom event though over trying to inspect a child model. What ever component that has "item.myData" should fire a custom event on tap with "item.myData" as part of the event. Then you should setup a listener for that custom event.

See [custom events](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events#custom-events) for more details.